# What is the meaning of p & s options given after running minikube start command?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am very new to the Kubernetes and Docker, and I am following the tutorials in the Kubernetes documentation.

I got the below output after running the `minikube start` command.

[image]

The process was paused for some time and after I entered `p` it continued, and the configuration was successfully completed.

Can I know what is the meaning for the two options given as p and s in the above output?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p/s means "per second"

That line is your machine pulling the relevant docker image(s) to start minikube.

Comment: So, doesn't the `?` mean it requires to enter an option? In my case it was paused until I entered `p`

Comment: No, the ? means it doesn't know the value yet -- normally this is because the pull hasn't started yet.

Comment: oh okay. So does that mean even if I didn't enter `p` after the output, it would have still processed and completed. I got this doubt because it was paused for so long and as soon as I entered `p` it resumed.

Comment: Yes, I just did the same thing on my local minikube with a k8s version I haven't pulled yet, and it did hang for a bit, but eventually continue without any user interaction.

Comment: gif showing my console output if you wish to compare with what you're getting: https://postimg.cc/G4nyMVsh